# Connecting ESP8266 (NodeMCU) with Android app (MIT APP inventor) especially the longitude and latitude from a gps module

Tags: arduino, gps, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, app-inventor

This is the value of latitude and longitude in my serial Arduino.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEqiI.png)

This is my example design in Mit App inventor
[image]

This is the blocks of my design in Mit app
[image]

Gps Code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 3, TXPin = 4;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop(){
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Nodemcu Esp8266

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* host = "GPS_NodeMCU";
const char* ssid = "GPS_BOT";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);


// Connecting WiFi

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid);
// Starting WEB-server

     server.on ( "/", HTTP_handleRoot );
     server.onNotFound ( HTTP_handleRoot );
     server.begin();    

}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
   delay(50);
}

void HTTP_handleRoot(void) {

if( server.hasArg("State") ){
       Serial.println(server.arg("State"));
  }
  server.send ( 200, "text/html", "" );
}
```

How to send the value of latitude and longitude in my serial using Arduino to my Map in my android application created in Mit App. The connection is using nodemcu esp8266.

Is it Possible to do?. Sorry, I'm just a beginner in the Arduino :) :)

Comment: you might want to ask in the MIT App Inventor community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/

Comment: Just to clarify: Is your GPS module connected to an ESP8266 or another Arduino board? And is the ESP8266 on the same wireless network as the phone running the MIT app inventor?

Comment: @BenT  yes sir the GPS module is connected to Nodemcu ESP8266. yes same wireless network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this but roughly speaking there are several problems to solve:

1. Read GPS data and make this accessible remotely
2. Fetch the data in the MIT app
3. (Bonus - part of the question in the comment) Lookup the address for the co-ordinates and display in the map

The example below implements a minumum solution and assumes that the MIT app has access to the ESP8266 on the same network.

### Read GPS data and make this accessible remotely

The ESP8266 can read the GPS data in a loop and make this accessible via the `ESP8266WebServer`. Here we implement a REST endpoint that returns the location as a JSON payload. So this location is available when a client does an HTTP GET on `http://esp8266-ip-address/location`.

You can test this with:

```
curl -XGET http://esp8266-ip-address/location
```

The key to combining the GPS and web server code is to combine the code in `loop()` and ensure that it is non-blocking. This allows both functions to do their tasks. e.g.

```
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  handleGpsData();
}

void handleGpsData() {
  while (ss.available() > 0) {
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    printGpsLocation();
  }
}
```

The full example Arduino code for this is:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

struct GpsLocation {
  float latitude;
  float longitude;
};

StaticJsonDocument<200> GpsLocationJson;

static const int RXPin = 3, TXPin = 4;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

TinyGPSPlus gps;

SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

const char* SSID = "GPS_NodeMCU";
const char* PASSWORD = "GPS_BOT";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(SSID);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.print("Connected. IP address: ");
  IPAddress ipAddress = WiFi.localIP();

  Serial.println(ipAddress);

  server.on("/location", handleLocation);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  handleGpsData();
}

void handleGpsData() {
  while (ss.available() > 0) {
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    printGpsLocation();
  }
}

void printGpsLocation() {
  if (gps.location.isUpdated()) {
    Serial.print("Latitude =");
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(" Longitude = ");
    Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6); 
  }
}

void handleLocation()
{
  auto requestMethod = server.method();
  if (requestMethod == HTTP_GET)
  {
    sendLocation();
  }
}

void sendLocation() {
  if (isGpsDataValid()) {
    auto location = getGpsLocation();
    GpsLocationJson["latitude"] = location.latitude;
    GpsLocationJson["longitude"] = location.longitude;

    String jsonString;
    serializeJson(GpsLocationJson, jsonString);

    server.send(200, "application/json", jsonString);
  } else {
    Serial.println("404: No GPS co-ordinates");
    server.send(404);
  }
}

bool isGpsDataValid() {
  return gps.location.isValid();
}

struct GpsLocation
getGpsLocation() {
  struct GpsLocation gpsLocation = {
    gps.location.lat(),
    gps.location.lng()
  };

  return gpsLocation;
}
```

### Fetch the data in the MIT app

The MIT App Inventor has a [Web Connectivity component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#Web) that can query the REST endpoint that was created in the previous step.

As an example, create a screen with these components:

- text box
- button
- map
- map marker
- web connectivity

The text box allows you to enter the IP address of the ESP8266.

Pressing the button retrieves the location from the ESP8266, pans the map location and moves the map marker.

See screenshots below. The example app has been published to http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/?galleryId=5471748170055680

The screen components:

[image]

Initialize the co-ordinates and create some helper procedures to manipulate co-ordinates and move the marker:

[image]

Handle the button click and the response from the ESP8266:

[image]

### Lookup the address for the co-ordinates and display in the map

This part was asked as a question in the comment.

There are many services to reverse geocode the co-ordinates. One example is the [Open Street Map Nominatim API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/).

This provides a simple GET endpoint that can be used like:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-34.44076&lon=144
```

The `display_name` property in the response has a formatted address.

This can be used by adding a second web connectivity component to the MIT app inventor screen. This component is named `ReverseGeocode` in this example.

Then create a function to get the address from the API:

[image]

and handle the response from the API:

[image]

Finally, modify the code that handles the response from the ESP8266 to invoke the new function:

[image]

The example code for this step is available at http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/?galleryId=5471748170055680#5320688868655104

Screenshot of the app:

[image]

Comment: It works thanks. But I'm confused is it possible to add address of my GPS module in the MIT App ?

Comment: I assume that you want to display a marker in the app? I've updated the answer to do this.

Comment: The changes include a [Map marker component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/maps.html#Marker) and the code to update its location.

Comment: Yes, this is one of I want this Map is applicable for the user who has Internet Access .What If the User has No Internet Access.  Is it possible to add text below of the Map and add the located address of GPS Module, For example, 123 ABC Street, Makati City, Philippines. Just like that Is it Possible?

Comment: There are almost two new questions in your comment here. I have updated the answer to include displaying the address. As for obtaining the map and address when there is no internet access - I don't think this is possible in MIT App inventor.

Please mark the answer as correct if you feel it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

To give a narrow answer to a broad question
You should use one of the tutorials to learn the basics of communication/protocols used: [See here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Temperature-Monitor-with-ESP8266-IoT/)
and then [dig into this](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/faq-section-arduino-and-wifi-esp8266/1665)